# "store and increment" microprocessor opcode

Tags: microprocessors

I am looking for an 8 bit microprocessor that, like the Sharp LH5801,
has a "store and increment" opcode ("41H" = A->(X), X + 1 ->X) without
all the extra baggage of that processor. It would be especially nice if
the processor had a "repeat" version of the opcode that would continue
until a second register down-counted to zero.
I have a simple graphics project that needs to load the same value into
hundreds of locations successively. It would be nice to load the accumulator
just once and then store it many times. As a reference, the Z80 can do
something similar, but it has to read the byte that it just wrote before it
can store it at the next location (it's an instruction for block moves).
I'm not concerned about compilers and libraries because I program in
machine language. As long as I have an opcode list for the processor, I'll
be able to make it work.
Has anyone worked with an 8-bit micro that could do this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of paragraphs

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve here? Off the top of my head PIC18F (MOVWF POSTINC0,A), AVR (ST X+,Rx) and 8051 (PUSH A) and HCS08 (MOV ,X+,opr8a) can store to post-incremented memory, though the last copies from memory. No 8-bit architecture springs to with repeated stores but you can always do an in-place forward copying of a seed character even through Z80 LDIR style block transfers.

Comment: Or, you know, just pick an architecture with fast DMA writes and leave the CPU out of it. Still, without further information it is difficult to see how this operation is sufficiently performance critical that the entire system must be optimized around it.

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to solve requires a very long answer. This